# Is there a R function for conditional values across different columns?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

Suppose you have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df <- tibble(PatientID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
         Treat1 = c("R", "O", "C", "O", "C"),
         Treat2 = c("O", "R", "R", NA, "O"),
         Treat3 = c("C", NA, "O", NA, "R"),
         Treat4 = c("H", NA, "H", NA, "H"),
         Treat5 = c("H", NA, NA, NA, "H"))
```

Treat 1:Treat5 are different treatments that a patient has had. I'm looking to create a new variable "Chemo" with  1 for yes, 0 for no based on whether a patient has had treatment "C".

I've been using if_else(), but as I have 10 different treatment variables in my actual dataset, and I would like to create such a column per treatment, i wonder if I can do it without writing such long if statements. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You mention that you need to create multiple treatment columns. In such a case, you could with something like `table(PatientID = rep(df$PatientID, ncol(df) - 1), Treatment = as.matrix(df[, -1])) > 0` at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if_any` to loop over the columns that `starts_with` 'Treat', create a logical vector with `%in%` - `if_any` returns `TRUE/FALSE` if any of the columns selected have 'C' for a particular row, the logical is converted to binary with `+` (or `as.integer`)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(Chemo = +(if_any(starts_with("Treat"), ~ .x %in% "C")))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  PatientID Treat1 Treat2 Treat3 Treat4 Treat5 Chemo
      <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1         1 R      O      C      H      H          1
2         2 O      R      <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       0
3         3 C      R      O      H      <NA>       1
4         4 O      <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>       0
5         5 C      O      R      H      H          1
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rowSums`

```
df$Chemo <- +(rowSums(df[startsWith(names(df), "Treat")] == "C", 
      na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `str_detect` and `any` to determine if `C` occurs in any of the `Treat` columns for each row. The `+` converts the logical to an integer.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Chemo = +any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with("Treat")), "C"), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

**Output**

```
  PatientID Treat1 Treat2 Treat3 Treat4 Treat5 Chemo
      <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1         1 R      O      C      H      H          1
2         2 O      R      NA     NA     NA         0
3         3 C      R      O      H      NA         1
4         4 O      NA     NA     NA     NA         0
5         5 C      O      R      H      H          1
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Treat"), ~case_when(.=="C" ~1,
                                                 TRUE ~0), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  mutate(Chemo = rowSums(select(., starts_with("new")))) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("new"))
```

```
  PatientID Treat1 Treat2 Treat3 Treat4 Treat5 Chemo
      <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1         1 R      O      C      H      H          1
2         2 O      R      NA     NA     NA         0
3         3 C      R      O      H      NA         1
4         4 O      NA     NA     NA     NA         0
5         5 C      O      R      H      H          1
```